# Property of series (grouping)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$(a_1+\dots+a_{n_1})+(a_{n_1+1}+\dots+a_{n_2})+\dots+(a_{n_k+1}+\dots+a_{n_{k+1}})+\dots$$ be a convergent series whose sum is $A.$ Also in each bracket is constant sign. If we delete brackets we got the series $\sum a_n$. How to prove that $\sum a_n=A$

**My proof sketch:** If $n_k\leqslant n\leqslant n_{k+1}$ then $A_{n_k}\leqslant A_n\leqslant A_{n_{k+1}}$ or $A_{n_k}\geqslant A_n\geqslant A_{n_{k+1}}$ because in each bracket is constant sign. If $k\to \infty$ then $A_{n_k}\to A$. How to prove that $A_n$ also tends to $A$? I know that here we can use Squeeze theorem but our index is $n$.

What relation between $n$ and $k$?

Can anyone well explain it to me?