# Sum of alternating series without alternating sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm not sure if I stated the problem correctly in the title, since my English is not very good, especially in mathematical terms. Given the following number series:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}$$

where the floor function $\lfloor t\rfloor$ - is operation of removing an integer part of a number, so $\lfloor\sqrt1\rfloor = 1$, $\lfloor\sqrt3\rfloor = 1$, $\lfloor\sqrt{10}\rfloor = 3$. How to check the convergence of a given series?

Comment: I upvoted the question, rather than downvoting it, because the math problem itself is very intriguing.  However, your posting, as is, is of low quality, because it is missing details.  It is plausible that your posting will be downvoted and not receive an answer (even if one is feasible), because of this.  If you are interested in improving the  quality of your posting, you can consult [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: @user2661923 I don't understand what do you find intriguing about this problem. It is very straightforward.

Comment: @user58697 Absolute value of the terms is strictly decreasing, but it is not a *pure* alternating series.  Instead, you have a group of positive elements, followed by a group of negative elements, and so forth, where the size of each group is strictly increasing.  My personal knowledge of real analysis is shallow enough, that I personally have no clue how to either attack the problem, or intuit one way or another, whether the sequence is convergent.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: the original question was modified. This answer addresses the original statement with $n$ in the denominator, then with $\sqrt{n}$.

The $1/n$ series has straightforward asymptotics as an alternating series $\sum(-1)^kb_k$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$ where $$b_k=\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}{\frac{1}{n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{(k+1)^2-1}{\frac{1}{n}}-\sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

The two sums on the right are the harmonic numbers $H$ indexed by $(k+1)^2-1$ and $k^2-1$ respectively. As $k\to \infty$, $$b_k\to \ln{\frac{k^2+2k}{k^2-1}}\to 0^+$$

As $b_k$ is strictly decreasing in $k$ asymptotically and converges to $0$, the series converges by the alternating series test.

Just as the simpler alternating harmonic series, it does converge conditionally, as $\sum |b_k|\to \infty$. So you should not rearrange the terms and subtract groups in a different order to find the limit.

Now, if you replace $1/n$ with $1/\sqrt{n}$, the series diverges. The modified $$b'_k=\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\geq \int_{k^2}^{(k+1)^2}{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}}=2$$

So the series in the tail, at best, looks like $+2-2+2-2\ldots$ which is not Cauchy. In the future please do not modify the question after an answer has been posted, you can post a new question.

Comment: Since only consecutive terms with the same sign are grouped, the grouping is valid: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789183/grouping-terms-of-a-series-with-the-same-sign

Comment: The idea is that, every individual partial sum, separately, positive or negative, decreases to zero, without having to subtract any pair of terms in the original sum

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome George! The integral $dx/\sqrt{x}$ has exactly the corresponding sum as left-hand Riemann approximation. Always a good place to look for convergence/divergence with $n^r$. A similar $dx/x$ integral probably works for $1/n$, but the harmonic numbers are well studied :)